# Deploying webservices on multihomed machines

Tags: osgi, cxf, equinox, dosgi

I am using Apache CXF through OSGi to expose my OSGi services as web services.  I am able to set the webservice uri through the "org.apache.cxf.ws.address" property, but this ties me to a single IP Address on the server.  Some services need to deploy on servers that are out of my control and so I would like to be able to deploy the services to all address on the server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the address to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all the network interfaces. In case you need to remove unneeded, then deploy firewall.

Comment: Fantastic!  I love simple answers!